# Rails 5: How to convert this named_scope to a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-2

Simple question I hope.

How do I convert this named_scope line from a rails 2  app into a scope line for rails 5

original...

```
  named_scope :effective_on, lambda { |date|
    { :conditions => ['(effective_on IS NULL OR effective_on <= ?) AND (ineffective_on IS NULL OR ineffective_on > ?)', date, date] }
  }
```

I've tried this but it is just printing out the conditions line as a string...

```
  scope :effective_on, lambda { |date|
    { :conditions => ['(effective_on IS NULL OR effective_on <= ?) AND (ineffective_on IS NULL OR ineffective_on > ?)', date, date] }
  }
```

I suspect that is because "conditions" is deprecated for Rails 5.0 but when I try to replace it with "where" in this version it explodes in my face...

```
  scope :effective_on, lambda { |date|
    { where('(effective_on IS NULL OR effective_on <= ?) AND (ineffective_on IS NULL OR ineffective_on > ?)', date, date) }
  }
```

... Explodes in my face: the entire "where" line lights up red in my IDE and it tells me "Expected: =>"

And this is where I am stumped.

Comment: you say `it explodes in my face`, what's the error?

Comment: @arieljuod updated the question with an explanation. I'm using Rubymine and it tells me it "Expected: =>" and so I am stuck in confusion.

Comment: you have an extra `{` `}` pair around the `where` method. do ` { |date| where(....) }`

Comment: Bingo, that was it. If you post that below as a solution I'll select it as the answer for your credit....thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the scope in the old Rails version returned a hash like `{ :conditions => 'some conditions }` but in newer version it returns an active record relation (like the return value of the `where` method)

So you have to change:

```rb
scope :effective_on, lambda { |date|
  { :conditions => ['(effective_on IS NULL OR effective_on <= ?) AND (ineffective_on IS NULL OR ineffective_on > ?)', date, date] }
}
```

to

```rb
scope :effective_on, lambda { |date|
  where('(effective_on IS NULL OR effective_on <= ?) AND (ineffective_on IS NULL OR ineffective_on > ?)', date, date)
}
```

without that `{` `}` around the `where` call